# invalid use of aggregate function in select

Tags: sql

**Tables**

```
Patient (patient_id, patient_name, gender, staff_no, ward_no)

Ward (ward_no, ward_name, number_of_beds)
```

**Query**

For each ward that has at least one patient in it, give the ward number and name together with the number of patients in the ward and the number of empty beds. Your answer should be presented in decreasing order of empty beds.

I've written the following SQL code and the server gives me an error:

> invalid use of an aggregate function

```
SELECT
    ward.ward_no,
    ward.ward_name,
    COUNT(*) AS patient_count, 
    number_of_beds - COUNT(patient_id) AS empty_beds
FROM
    patient,
    ward
WHERE
    patient.ward_no = ward.ward_no
GROUP BY
    ward.ward_no,
    ward.ward_name,
    number_of_beds,
    empty_beds
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY
    ward.ward_name
```

Can anyone help? I need to calculate a number of empty beds and return it as as a column.

Thanks in advance

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't group by `empty_beds` unless you return it in your SELECT statement (using SQL Server)

```
SELECT ward.ward_no, ward.ward_name, COUNT(*) AS patient_count, 
number_of_beds - COUNT(patient_id) AS empty_beds
FROM patient, ward
WHERE patient.ward_no = ward.ward_no
GROUP BY ward.ward_no, ward.ward_name, number_of_beds HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY ward.ward_name
```

Comment: many thanks.. i changed the last line to ORDER BY empty_beds DESC to reflect the query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  w.ward_no, ward_name, patient_count, number_of_beds - patient_count AS empty_beds
FROM    (
        SELECT  ward_no, COUNT(*) AS patient_count
        FROM    patient
        GROUP BY
                ward_no
        ) p
JOIN    ward w
ON      w.ward_no = p.ward_no
ORDER BY
        empty_beds DESC
```